# What is it, Million or Mega?

Tags: grammatical-number

Twitter followers, YouTube views and so many other places we see the use of shorthand version of numbers.

1,000 becomes 1k
100,000 becomes 100k
1,000,000 becomes 1m
and so on.

1,000,000,000 (a billion) becomes 1b / 1B

We all remember Justin Bieber's Baby hitting that number on YouTube, right? No? Anyways, who cares.

So, coming back to my question.

If it is 1K for a thousand, and not 1T where T stands for Thousands, does that mean the M in 1M stands for Mega, like in (Kilo, Mega, Giga etc.., computer storage / memory units we all know and love)

Then why is 1B not 1G. Is there something I am missing or should we be thankful to the ever inconsistent nature of rogue developers and programmers messing things up for decades by one decision they took at 3am during a coding sprint, and decided 1K for a thousand, but 1M for a million, and that M stands for Million, not Mega like it should.

Is it in reality inconsistent or am I missing any key details of how Kilo, Mega, Giga is supposed to be used when writing shorthand version of numbers?

Comment: Hardly anyone uses **B** to mean a billion, or **T** to represent a thousand. But to confuse you further, one **G** (grand) is a thousand dollars, pounds etc. Many words have a lot of meanings too, which we usually disambiguate from the context.

Comment: There are many different jargons used around the world by different groups, including criminals, bankers/financiers, mathematicians, programmers, and general colloquialisms, all of which have differences but still interact. (For instance, when k means 1024 and when it means 1000). This question could do with clarification/focus.

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviations for monetary values seen in newspaper headlines and other contexts formed from multiple sources:

- K for thousand, from *kilo-* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/k))
- M for million, from *million* ([Wiktionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/m))
- B for billion, from *billion* ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/B))

No, these are not consistent with the SI amount abbreviations (K, M, G, etc.). Nor are they consistent with Latin abbreviations (M [mille] for a thousand) or other slang (G [grand] for a thousand). They are not internally consistent. That's just how the usage cookie crumbles. They are shorthand abbreviations for money, often in a journalistic context for headlines (see [AP Stylebook](https://apstylebook.com/) [paywalled, but also accessible in print], "K" and "millions, billions, trillions").

Abbreviations in AP tend toward what readers are familiar with. People may know what a *billion dollars* is (in theory) but are not accustomed to thinking of a *gigadollar*, so B is used; people have seen K enough to read $24K as twenty-four thousand dollars.